# Postgresql unique constraint for colums of multiple related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

**server** (server_id as PK)

```
server_id |  server_name
----------+---------------
 3251623  |  ServerOfDoom
 5578921  |  BestServerEU
```

**server_groups**
*Each server can have multiple `server groups`, every group name within a `server` must be unique.*

```
 id | server_id |  group_name
----+-----------+---------------
  1 |  3251623  | mods
  2 |  5578921  | admins
  3 |  5578921  | anothergroup
```

**group_tags**
*Each group can have multiple `tags`, a tag can be connected to multiple `groups`. Each `tag name` must be unique.*

```
 id | tag_name
----+--------------
  1 | mods
  2 | admins
  3 | ag
```

**group_tag_relations**

```
 group_id | tag_id
----------+--------
        2 |      1
        3 |      3
        1 |      2
```

### Problem:

I need `group tag names` and `server group names` to be `unique within one server`. So a `tag` can be connected to multiple `groups`, but only to **one group per server**. Or the `tag "foo"` cannot be connected to the `group "bar"` of `server z` because `server z` already has a `group "foo"`. The same goes for the other way around, so if the `group "foo"` had the `tag "hey"` you shouldn't be able to add a `group "hey"` to the same server.

Basically names should not appear multiple times on a server, no matter if tag or group name.

***How would I implement such a Constraint?***

### EDIT

So basically I'm trying to convert this JSON format into SQL tables:

```
{
    "5578921": {
        "Server Name": "Server1",
        ...
        "Groups": {
            "Game1": {
                "Tags": [
                    "g1",
                    "gameone"
                ], ...
            },
            "Game2": {
                "Tags": [
                    "g2",
                    "gametwo"
                ], ...
            }
        }
    },
    "3251623": ...
}
```

The id's 5578921 and 3251623 should just represent Discord server id's, so every id is for one server my bot is on. The Json file is all the information of my bot for each server, but it's not as reliable and scalable as a database, so I wanted to convert it.

So the upper tables are what I came up with:

A **One-To-Many relation** between `server` and `server_groups` and a **Many-To-Many relation** between `server_groups` and `group_tags` (so instead of storing duplicate tags I can just assign them to different groups).

I just want to make sure there are no duplicate names on one server and asking how to do so for my current tables.

Comment: What does "How would I query such a constraint?" mean?  Are you asking how to implement such a constraint?

Comment: This is a mess. It would be better if you explained what you are trying to do with your categorization of servers and then we could work from that to a solution.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe its a bit clearer now.

Comment: Also I dont quiet get how these tables are a mess? They are standard relationship tables, as far as I've seen.

Comment: It's unclear to me from the JSON structure why a server can't have a group and a tag with the same name. `"Groups": { "Game1": { "Tags": ["Game1"] } }` seems fine. This doesn't seem like a structural constraint, but business constraint. It might make sense to enforce it with a trigger.

Comment: So basically for my current Bot, you can create groups, join them, and then call them by name or alias to ping everybody in that group (simplified). So I can't have multiple groups with the same name or alias on a server, since that would lead to multiple unwanted pings. Or if someone wanted to change a name of a group, the command would be "change name of ... to ..." in which case multiple group names would be changed if they had the same alias or name. Thus I need to limit a server to unique names.

Comment: The json until this point is Python generated so my Python code takes care of no duplicates, but it'd be greater to have an SQL solution instead having to check it in Python.

Comment: You can't implement these as a type of constraint on the table itself, so you should probably place the logical checks into a stored procedure. I suppose you could make it a trigger for INSERT or UPDATE against either table, but I imagine you'd want stored procedures already to encapsulate your behavior for your interface layer to call, so placing this logic there would be seamless.

Comment: I've looked a bit through Stored Procedures now, and they seem the way to go, thanks. Just haven't figured out yet how to write the Precedure in this case...

Comment: @EînEînhorn, can we make it even more restrictive and say that all names (tag names and group names) must be globally unique? For example, once you create a group called `"foo"`, you can't create a tag called `"foo"`, even if that tag is used somewhere else. If yes, it might be possible to implement all these constraints declaratively without denormalizing your tables too much .

Comment: @EînEînhorn, or other way around, can we allow a group and a tag with the same name on the same server? Groups would be unique within a server. Tags would be unique within a server. But, there can be a tag and a group with the same name on the same server. Is this acceptable? You can have two different commands to change the name of the groups and tags: `change groupname of ... to ...` and `change tagname of ... to ...`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The scenario is that if you say ".play foo" my bot looks for any group on the server that has the tag or name foo, and if theres multiple groups the bot would answer multiple times which is not the wanted result. Only thing I could do is that tags are allowed to have the same name as the group they are assigned to, but that'd rather make it more complicated I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of *suffering* I finally got what I wanted:

**Get all Tags of a server**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_server_tags(serverid BIGINT) 
RETURNS TABLE(group_name VARCHAR(100), tag_name VARCHAR(100), group_id BIGINT, tag_id BIGINT)
AS
$$
    SELECT group_name, tag_name, group_id, tag_id FROM group_tag_relations 
    JOIN server_groups 
    ON server_groups.server_id = serverid
    AND server_groups.id = group_tag_relations.group_id
    JOIN group_tags
    ON group_tags.id = group_tag_relations.tag_id
$$
language sql
stable;
```

**Get all Groups of a server**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_server_group(serverid BIGINT, groupname VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS TABLE(group_name VARCHAR(100), group_id BIGINT)
AS
$$
    SELECT group_name, id
    FROM server_groups 
    WHERE server_id = serverid 
    AND lower(group_name) = lower(groupname);
$$
language sql
stable;
```

**Get a Group by Name (Calling both Functions above)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_group_by_name(serverid BIGINT, groupname VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE(group_name VARCHAR(100), group_id BIGINT)
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT get_server_group.group_name, get_server_group.group_id
    FROM get_server_group(serverid, groupname);

    IF NOT found THEN 
        RETURN QUERY SELECT get_server_tags.group_name, get_server_tags.group_id
        FROM get_server_tags(serverid)
        WHERE lower(tag_name) = lower(groupname);
    END IF;
END;
$$
language plpgsql
stable;
```

**Update Trigger for `server_groups` table, checking wether the name is already taken on a server**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_name_update() 
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$ 
BEGIN
    PERFORM get_group_by_name(OLD.server_id, NEW.group_name);
    
    IF lower(OLD.group_name) = lower(NEW.group_name) THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF found THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$
language plpgsql
volatile;


CREATE TRIGGER group_name_update_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE ON server_groups
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE group_name_update();
```

**Insert Trigger for `server_groups` table, checking wether the name is already taken on a server**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_name_insert() 
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$ 
BEGIN
    PERFORM get_group_by_name(NEW.server_id, NEW.group_name);

    IF found THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$
language plpgsql
volatile;

CREATE TRIGGER group_name_insert_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON server_groups
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE group_name_insert();
```

**Insert Trigger for `group_tag_relation` table, checking wether the tag is already taken on a server (as the tags wont get updated there's no need for an update trigger)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_tag_relation_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$ 
BEGIN
    PERFORM get_group_by_name((SELECT server_id FROM server_groups WHERE id = NEW.group_id), (SELECT tag_name FROM group_tags WHERE id = tag_id));

    IF found THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$
language plpgsql
volatile;

CREATE TRIGGER group_tag_relation_insert_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON group_tag_relations
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE group_tag_relation_insert();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, a stored procedure or function with triggers is probably the way to go.

The code could look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."CHECK_TAG_AND_GROUP_NAME_UNIQUE_PER_SERVER"()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
     NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    countServerGroupsWithNamePerServer  integer;
    countGroupTagsWithNamePerServer     integer;
BEGIN

    -- Count occurrences of name in server_groups table
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM server_groups
    INTO countServerGroupsWithNamePerServer
    WHERE "name" = NEW.name
        AND "server_id" = NEW.server_id;
        
    -- Check if one exists. If it does, throw error
    IF countServerGroupsWithNamePerServer > 0 THEN
        RAISE 'Name already exists as a group server name %', NEW.name;
    END IF;

    -- Count occurrences of name in group_tags table
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM group_tags
    INTO countGroupTagsWithNamePerServer
    WHERE "name" = NEW.name
        AND "server_id" = NEW.server_id;

    -- Check if one exists. If it does, throw error
    IF countGroupTagsWithNamePerServer > 0 THEN
        RAISE 'Name already exists as a group_tag name %', NEW.name;
    END IF;

    -- If no error is thrown, insert the new record
    RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$;
```

and then you attach the function as a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to each of the two tables `group_tags` and `server_groups`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "BEFORE_INSERT_CHECK_TAG_NAME_UNIQUE_PER_SERVER"
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.group_tags
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public."CHECK_TAG_AND_GROUP_NAME_UNIQUE_PER_SERVER"();


CREATE TRIGGER "BEFORE_INSERT_CHECK_TAG_NAME_UNIQUE_PER_SERVER"
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.server_groups
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public."CHECK_TAG_AND_GROUP_NAME_UNIQUE_PER_SERVER"();
```

---

Please notice for this example I also added a foreign key column `server_id` to the `group_tags` table. Otherwise we are not sure to which server the tag belongs. This is just a rough guide though, please feel free to change it up as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found out a bit since I asked my question, so I answered it mostly myself now, but the trigger part helped me a lot anyway :)